# Prove that process satisfy Bessel equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

$[W_t^1,...,W_t^n]$ - n-dimensional Wiener process, $R_t=\left(\sum_{n=1}^n(W_t^i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}, M_t=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_0^t\frac{W_s^i}{R_s}dW_s^i$ and I have to show that

$dR_t=dM_t+\frac{n-1}{2R_t}dt$

I try to use multidimensional Ito Formula to solve it but I didn't get anything sensible.

Comment: Itô's lemma is the way to do it though how are using it in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:** It may be easier to proceed in two steps. First apply Ito to $S_t:=R_t^2 =f(W_t)$, where $f(x):=\|x\|^2$ (so that $\nabla f(x) =2x$ and $\Delta f(x) = 2n$). This should yield
$$
dS_t = W_t\cdot dW_t+ n\,dt= R_t\,dM_t+n\,dt.
$$
(Notice that that $\langle S\rangle_t = 4\int_0^t W_s^2\,ds$.)
Then apply Ito a second time to $R_t=S^{1/2}_t$.